# Virtual hosts pointing to the same directory

Tags: virtualhost, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a server with Kloxo and two virtual hosts. They are pointed to the same IP, but a different directory.

Here's the config of virtual host files. They're in different files, and included in the main httpd.conf file. NameVirtualHost *:80 is uncommented.

arturas.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin arturas@duomenucentras.lt
    DocumentRoot /home/.sites/_default/web
    ServerName arturas.duomenucentras.lt:80
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/.sites/_default/cgi-bin/
    ErrorLog /home/.sites/_default/logs/error_log
    TransferLog /home/.sites/_default/logs/access_log
    <Directory /home/.sites/_default/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options +Includes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

donkapone.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin arturas@duomenucentras.lt
    DocumentRoot /home/.sites/donkapone/web
    ServerName www.donkapone.duomenucentras.lt:80
    ServerAlias donkapone.duomenucentras.lt:80
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/.sites/donkapone/cgi-bin
    <Directory /home/.sites/donkapone/web>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options +Includes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

both of the sites show Kloxo Default Page as an error. Both of the subdomains, when pinged ping arturas.duomenucentras.lt

> If you are seeing this page, it means that web has not been configured for this domain on this server.
>
> This could be due to the following causes:
>
> Kloxo has not restarted the web server yet after you added the domain. Please wait for the web server to restart.
>
> The domain is pointing to the wrong Kloxo server. Ping the domain and make sure that the IP matches one of the IPaddress seen in admin home -> ipaddresses
>
> If you are seeing this page when you try to access an IP like http://192.168.1.1, then that means that the IP has not yet been mapped to a domain. Go to client home -> ipaddresses -> ipaddress home -> domain config and map an IP to a domain.
>
> Once you map an IP to a domain, then you have to make sure that the domain pings back to the same IP. Otherwise, if you try to access the domain, you will get this page. So IP -> domain.com should mean that domain.com pings to the same IP.

I'm guessing that's the root of the problems.

Any idea why does it do that?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like a standard Apache config, but I have never used the :80 on the ServerName lines in mine.

The ping thing is normal, because you are using virtual hosts.  This means they share the same IP address, so if you use the standard unix ping command that looks up the reverse address, then it will resolve to only one of the names (usually.)

Apache doesn't care about the reverse name, only the forward one.

Answer (score 0):

The :80 isn't part of the server name, I'd remove that from the ServerName and ServerAlias values.

ping has nothing to do with your HTTP setup, what you are seeing is effectively the canonical name of the server don't worry about that.

Comment: I fixed the :80 in Servername and ServerAlias, and restarted apache, but Kloxo is still showing it's Default Page. I've updated the error in the original post.

Comment: How did you include arturas.conf in httpd.conf?

Comment: Have you placed a different index.html in each ServerRoot?

Comment: It's included like so:

Include /etc/httpd/vhost/arturas.conf
Include /etc/httpd/vhost/donkapone.conf

And yes, two different sites are uploaded to 
home/.sites/_default/web
and to /home/.sites/donkapone/web

Comment: It was working great, when it was only one site - the Kloxo Default Page appeared when I added another Virtual Host.

Comment: Kloxo itself works, though, when I access it through 7778 port.

Comment: You say "both of the sites show Kloxo Default Page as an error" - is there a numeric error code? Is there a corresponding entry in any of the error logs? I'd check the default log as well as the vhost specific logs.

Comment: [Tue Nov 16 13:38:14 2010] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 16 13:39:08 2010] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Nov 16 13:39:08 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Nov 16 13:39:08 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Nov 16 13:39:08 2010] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 10 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Nov 16 13:39:08 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
that's the httpd error log. There's no numeric error, just that page in the OP

Comment: Is this your own server or a VPS? Are you doing some edits manually and some via Kloxo?

Comment: that's a VPS. What kind of edits? I have done any via Kloxo. Everything's done via shell.

Comment: I imagine the changes you are making via the shell may be inconsistent with changes that Kloxo has introduced. Since you have a VPS and not shared hosting, I'd ignore Kloxo and reset the httpd.conf to a *standard Apache default state* and then add the vhosts manually. I'd start by putting the vhost directives in the main file rather than including them. If that worked, maybe move them to separate files - if that's what you prefer.

Comment: Kloxo included these in the httpd.conf:
mimetype.conf, domainin.conf, ssl.conf, default.conf, webmail_redirect.conf, webmail.conf, cp_config.conf, init.conf, virtualhost.conf, forwardhost.conf.

Comment: I've commented the Kloxo includes in httpd.conf and placed virtual hosts into the httpd.conf. It is working now. Even Kloxo is working through 7778 port - but how can it, if i commented over all those includes?

Answer (score 0):

As heavily documented, *the first-listed virtual host is always the default one* when no other virtualhost matches the Host: header.

You are not requesting the ServerName or ServerAlias of the second vhost; hence, the first one is returned.